# Inclusion of fractional ideals implies equality

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a integral domain and let $\mathfrak U\subseteq\mathfrak B$ two ideals of $R$ such that $\mathfrak UR_\mathfrak p=\mathfrak BR_\mathfrak p$ for all maximal ideals. Then $\mathfrak U=\mathfrak B$.

**Proof:** Let $b\in \mathfrak B$. For each maximal ideal $\mathfrak p$, we have $bR_\mathfrak p\subseteq \mathfrak UR_\mathfrak p$. So there is some $a\in \mathfrak U$ and some $s\in R\setminus\mathfrak p$ such that $b=a/s$. The ideal of $R$ defined by

$$\{y\in R: by\in\mathfrak U\}$$

must contains $s$ and so it does not belong to $\mathfrak p$. This ideal is not contained in any   maximal  ideal so it must be all of $R$. Thus $b=1b\in\mathfrak U$ as required.

**My question is:** if the above proof holds if $\mathfrak U,\mathfrak B$ are fractional ideals of $R$.

I think so, I'm not entirely sure.

Thanks.

Comment: If $\mathfrak{U}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ are fractional ideals of $R$, then there exist nonzero $g, h \in R$ such that $g\mathfrak{U}$ and $h\mathfrak{B}$ are actual ideals of $R$. Then, you can apply the statement at the beginning of your post to $gh\mathfrak{U}$ and $gh\mathfrak{B}$ instead of $\mathfrak{U}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$. So the result holds for fractional ideals (because you can cancel out $gh$ again, due to $R$ being an integral domain). This said, my experience with fractional ideals is limited to a 12-page note by Keith Conrad, so please take this with a grain of salt...

Comment: If $M$ is an $R$-module and $N$ a submodule such that $M_p=N_p$ for all primes $p$, then $M=N$. This has not much to do with ideals, fractional or otherwise.